# OpenJDK Type Inference Compilation Error

Tags: javac, java

I have this piece of code that fails to compile on OpenJDK Linux, but not Oracle JDK on Windows, both 1.7 (Linux - javac 1.7.0_79 specifically):

*OS is an enum, Path is an enum as well.*

```
public static Map<OS, Map<Path, String>> paths = new HashMap<>();
```

...

```
paths.put(OS.WINDOWS, new HashMap<>()); // FAIL ON OPEN JDK!!!!
```

And I get this error:

```
required: OS,Map<Path,String>
   found: OS,HashMap<Object,Object>
   reason: actual argument HashMap<Object,Object> cannot be converted to Map<Path,String> by method invocation conversion
```

If I don't rely on type inference and put in generics directly, it works.

```
public static Map<OS, Map<Path, String>> paths = new HashMap<OS, Map<Path, String>>();
```

...

```
paths.put(OS.WINDOWS, new HashMap<Path, String>()); // NOT FAIL ON OPENJDK
```

Is this a bug, or old version of OpenJDK?

**EDIT:
Problem solved!
On Windows I was using Java 8 with target type inference. Thanks shmosel.**

Comment: It could be a bug, I would make sure your have the latest version.  Ideally I would switch to Java 8.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using 1.8 on Windows?

Comment: @shmosel Oh wow, I am using 1.8, sorry. Have generic type inferences changed in 1.8?

Comment: Yes, 1.8 added target type inference. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) for more info.